# How to compute the area and format it in a table?

Tags: python

This is my homework:

> Write a program that computes the area of a square, triangle, circle,
> and a rectangle. The program then prints the output in nicely
> formatted table as shown in the example below. Your program should be
> implemented with at least 3 function and docstrings. You should create
> a new module “area_tools” with the following functions in it:
> `Square(base)`, `Triangle(base,height)`, `Circle(radius)`, and
> `Rectangle(base,height)`. Your main program should use the functions in
> your module.
>
> ```
> Example of the table:
>
> Vars | square | Triangle | circle | rectangle
>
> 10,10 | 100 | ??? | 345.56 | 4567
> ```

I know I did it wrong and I don't know how to go from here. I get an error message saying:

`TypeError: Square() missing 1 required positional argument: 'base'`

I really don't know what to do. This is what I've done so far. In a file named area_tools.py, I did this:

```
 def Triangle():
    '''Finds the area of the triangle'''
    base = int(input("Enter the base: "))
    height = int(input("Enter the height: "))
    triangle_area = (base * height) / 2
    return triangle_area

def Rectangle():
    '''Finds the area of the rectangle'''
    base = int(input("Enter the base: "))
    height = int(input("Enter the height: "))
    rectangle_area = base * height
    return rectangle_area

def Circle():
    '''Finds the area of the circle'''
    radius = int(input("Enter the radius: "))
    pi = 3.14159
    circle_area = pi * radius ** 2
    return circle_area

def Square():
  base = int(input("Enter the base: "))
  square_area = base ** 2
  return square_area
```

In a second file, I did this:

```
import area_tools
import pandas as pd

data = {'square': [Square()],
        'triangle': [Triangle()],
        'circle': [Circle()],
        'rectangle': [Rectangle()],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['square', 'triangle', 'circle','rectangle'])
df
```

EDIT: I copied and pasted the code on here so it's easier to see what I'm talking about: https://repl.it/@fgffdsfj/StrangeInfantileDisks#main.py

Comment: One thing that's wrong: use `import area_tools` (leave the `.py` off at the end). You will need to prefix call to them with the module name: e.g. `area_tools.Triangle(…)`

Comment: `input()` always gives string and you have to convert to number using `int()` or `float()`

Comment: what do you try to do with `{'square': [Square()]` ? In this moment you run function `Square()` but it needs values - `Square(values)` - to calculate result. If you use `input()` inside `Square` then don't use variables in definition - `def Square():`

Comment: @furas Thank you! your suggestions helped a lot! There is no error, but my code does nothing now. It asks the questions and once I give the answers, it doesn't do anything. It just stops. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @furas If you don't mind, can you see my edit, please?

Comment: as for me you should use `input()` outside functions and then you can ask for `base`, `height`, `radius`) only once and use the same values in all functions as argumensts `Square(base)`, `Triangle(base,height)`, `Circle(radius)`, and `Rectangle(base,height)`. You can keep results in dataframe but you could also keep results in normal variables and use string formatting to display table - `"{:5}, {:5} | {:10} | {:10} | {:10} | {:10} ".format(base, height, result_square, result_triangle, result_circle, result_rectangle)` (or something more complex)

Comment: BTW: don't change original code in question but add new changes at the end of question. You changed code and now answer below does fit to this code. it was usefull asnwer for old code but now it is useless answer.

Comment: BTW: if you run code in script then you have to use `print()` to display `df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `input()` outside your functions and send values as arguments

```
def Triangle(base, height):
    '''Finds the area of the triangle'''
    return base * height / 2

def Rectangle(base, height):
    '''Finds the area of the rectangle'''
    return base * height

def Circle(radius):
    '''Finds the area of the circle'''
    pi = 3.14159
    return pi * radius ** 2

def Square(base):
    return base ** 2

my_base   = int(input("Enter the base/width/radius: "))
my_height = int(input("Enter the height: "))
#my_radius = int(input("Enter the radius: "))

# only for fast test
#my_base   = 3
#my_height = 4

result_square = Square(my_base)
result_triangle = Triangle(my_base, my_height)
result_circle = Circle(my_base)
result_rectangle = Rectangle(my_base, my_height)
```

And later you can use string formatting (align to left, right or center) to create table.

```
print('| {:^7} | {:^10} | {:^10} | {:^10} | {:^10} |'.format('Vars', 'Square', 'Triangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle'))
print('| {:>3},{:<3} | {:^10} | {:^10} | {:^10} | {:^10} |'.format(my_base, my_height, result_square, result_triangle, result_circle, result_rectangle))
```

Result

```
|  Vars   |   Square   |  Triangle  |   Circle   | Rectangle  |
|   3,4   |     9      |    6.0     |  28.27431  |     12     |
```

More about string formatting on [PyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

Answer (score 2):

In the **Second file** when you call function your didn't send any argument to function that why it return an error

You can remove argument to function in **First file** and get from input instead

```
def Triangle():
    '''Finds the area of the triangle'''
    base = int(input("Enter the base: "))
    height = int(input("Enter the height: "))
    triangle_area = (base * height) / 2
    return triangle_area

def Rectangle():
    '''Finds the area of the rectangle'''
    base = int(input("Enter the base: "))
    height = int(input("Enter the height: "))
    rectangle_area = base * height
    return rect_area

def Circle():
    '''Finds the area of the circle'''
    radius = int(input("Enter the radius: "))
    circle_area = pow(math.pi * radius, 2)
    return circle_area
```

Comment: New error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @anon_misid `input()` always gives string and you have to convert to number using `int()` or `float()`